# Function parameter passing in JavaScript with Google Chrome API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble with the Chrome API. Specifically, I can't seem to pass anything from my context menu onclick function.

```
var linkSafetyChild = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title":"Is this link safe?","parentId":linkParent,"contexts":[contexts[2]],"onclick":checkScamAdvisorLink});
```

which calls the function:

```
function checkScamAdvisorLink(info, tab){   alert(info.mediaType);
var searchString = "http://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/";
alert(info.linkURL);
var siteToCheck = convertURLToSearchableString(info.linkURL);
var finalString = searchString.concat(siteToCheck); }
```

but when I try to access the info object with alert(info.mediaType) and alert(info.linkURL) both return undefined. How can I pass this information to checkScamAdvisorLink?

The above excerpts are from launch.js specified in the manifest.

Manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name":"Hi-Brite Informational Assistant",
"description": "This extension provides extended information and performs various helpful actions based on highlighted text. Just kidding, it does nothing",

"version": "0.0.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup":"my_popup.html"
},

"permissions": ["activeTab", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/", "contextMenus","tabs"],

"background":{
    "scripts":["launch.js"]
},

"content_scripts":[{
        "matches": ["https://www.tineye.com/"],
        "js":["TinyEyeSearch.js"]
}]}
```

Comment: Please add the code where `contexts` array is defined.

Comment: contexts is just defined in launch.js var contexts = ["page","selection","link","image","video","audio"];

Comment: I think `info.linkURL` may be `undefined` only in one case: you use one onclick handler for different types of contexts AND you invoke your context menu item for something which isn't link.

Comment: Shameless bump ##############

Comment: Zip a simple sample extension to test and link it here.